# Jumping directly through a scrollable section using jquerytools scrollable

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable

We are implementing a vertical scrollable - similar to

http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/vertical.html

using jquerytools Scrollable.

There is a business requirement that we can jump directly to an arbitrary section within
the scrollable (e.g. by specifying the target section through the anchor name 
e.g.

http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/vertical.html#section-3

Is this supported by jquerytools scrollable?

It is working for the jquerytools tabs implementation but does not seem to have an effect on the scrollable module.